# Trigger local Jenkins build with a push to a Bitbucket repository

Tags: macos, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

So I currently have Jenkins setup on a Mac Mini that is connected to my local network. What I would like to do is have Jenkins execute a build when a push is made to my remote Git repository on Bitbucket. Based on the research that I have done so far, there are people who use Bitbucket POST hook to notify Jenkins when a push is made to the repository. However, this method seems to work if Jenkins is hosted on a remote server. Is there a way to trigger a local Jenkins build from a remote Git repository? Perhaps there is a specific plugin that I should install?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose your Jenkins machine to the world, you can instead have it [poll your Git repository](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Buildsbysourcechanges) looking for changes:

> ### Builds by source changes
>
> You can have Jenkins poll your Revision Control System for changes. You can specify how often Jenkins polls your revision control system using the same syntax as crontab on Unix/Linux. However, if your polling period is shorter than it takes to poll your revision control system, you may end up with multiple builds for each change. You should either adjust your polling period to be longer than the amount of time it takes to poll your revision control system, or use a post-commit trigger. You can examine the *Polling Log* for each build to see how long it took to poll your system.
>
> Alternatively, instead of polling on a fixed interval, you can use a URL trigger (described above), but with `/polling` instead of `/build` at the end of the URL. This makes Jenkins poll the SCM for changes rather than building immediately. This prevents Jenkins from running a build with no relevant changes for commits affecting modules or branches that are unrelated to the job. When using `/polling` the job must be configured for polling, but the schedule can be empty.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing now. I think that the Github plugin has this feature. I wanted to see if there was a way to trigger builds without having Jenkins to poll the SCM.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to trigger a build directly on a push is to open up a port on your firewall so that BitBucket (or GitHub, or whatever) can communicate directly with Jenkins.